# Understanding relationship between new xacro macros and --inorder

Tags: ros-jade, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just learned of the new Jade xacro macros as part of [a PR](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/pull/117#issuecomment-372887599) I submitted. In switching to using `${radians(foo)}`, the build [failed](https://travis-ci.org/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/builds/353158609). In comparing to other robots in the `kuka_experimental` repository, I found a few differences, one of which being the `--inorder` flag. I [was informed](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/issues/120) that these new Jade macros require `--inorder`, but I didn't see that on the wiki.

I've updated the wiki on [math expressions](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Math_expressions) to suggest using `--inorder`, but I'm still a bit confused by the behavior and thought I'd bring it here in case there were further doc changes that might be helpful.

For one, I updated two robot `macros.xacro` files to use `${radians()}` for their joint limits. One failed (linked above), and one [succeeded](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/pull/118). Changing the first to use `--inorder` fixed the build error. The second still doesn't have it, yet this somehow passes the build?

```
<launch>
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find kuka_lbr_iiwa_support)/urdf/lbr_iiwa_14_r820.xacro'" />
</launch>
```

Secondly, [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order) suggests that one can test whether or not this flag affects
their `xacro` files with:

```
rosrun xacro xacro file.xacro > /tmp/old.xml
rosrun xacro xacro --inorder file.xacro > /tmp/new.xml
diff /tmp/old.xml /tmp/new.xml
```

I assumed that if `--inorder` was the source of issues, I'd detect it with this test? In trying that on `lbr_iiwa_14_r820_macro.xacro` and `lbr_iiwa_14_r820.xacro` in [this branch](https://github.com/jwhendy/kuka_experimental/tree/lbr_14_r820_tweaks/kuka_lbr_iiwa_support) of `kuka_experimental`, I get no results for either using `diff` (identical output).

Could someone with more macros experience help illuminate what's going on here and suggest any changes I could make to the wiki to help others? I found this to be pretty nuanced/subtle, and it caused maybe an hour of trying random things, waiting for a Travis build, and repeating. It'd be nice to help other users avoid this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285710/understanding-relationship-between-new-xacro-macros-and---inorder/) by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2018-03-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've commented on the issue you opened over at `ros-industrial/kuka_experimental`: [ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/issues/120 - comment](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/issues/120#issuecomment-373986816).

In short: `--inorder` is not needed on Jade and newer to enable the new xacro features. Those are enabled by default.

It *was* needed to enable "in order processing" of xacros on Jade. This was done to allow for a transition period in which users could test their xacros with the new `xacro`.

The `--inorder` flag *is* needed if you want to make use of the new `xacro` features on Indigo. This just makes Indigo `xacro` behave like Jade+ xacro.

> I've updated the wiki on [math expressions](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Math_expressions) to suggest using `--inorder`, but I'm still a bit confused by the behavior and thought I'd bring it here in case there were further doc changes that might be helpful.

I hope it's now clear that `--inorder` is not needed to enable these new features, *unless* you are on Indigo. I would suggest to revert your changes, or clarify this is only needed for Indigo.

---

For some context, see [ros/xacro#110](https://github.com/ros/xacro/issues/110), specifically Morgan's [comment](https://github.com/ros/xacro/issues/110#issuecomment-144593204).

Additionally, see [ros/xacro#117](https://github.com/ros/xacro/pull/117) where this got merged.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2018-03-18**:
Thank you for clarifying and the PR was immensely helpful to understanding what was going on. I now see that this is just serving as a way to trigger access to Jade+ features from Indigo. Thanks!